# Taking a polymorphism approach?

Tags: c#, polymorphism

I am currently writing a game server.

I have a class called `NetMessage`. This class acts as an intermediate between byte arrays sent over a network.

When the server receives the byte array it changes it back into a `NetMessage` and makes a list of these, handing that to a manager.

`NetMessage` is an abstract class, so all messages derive from it but when the data arrives to the `GameManager`, it can have to do vastly different things with the data it gets.

For example, a `NetMoveMessage` needs to be handled differently than a `NetConnectMessage`.

Also, the messages themselves don't have any methods besides serializing themselves and cannot themselves alter the state. Only the manager can, so they are essentially just data classes.

Right now to decide what to do with the data I am simply checking what type of message it is. For example

```
            NetMessage message = IncomingMessages.First.Value;
            IncomingMessages.RemoveFirst();  

            if(message is NetConnectMessage)
            {
                //cool things here
            }
            else if(message is NetMoveMessage)
            {
                //Isn't this exciting?
            }
```

Is this bad practice? Is there a better way to do this? It seems fine to me considering the messages are not doing anything, so the only way to read the data would be to determine what the data is that needs to be read someway and handle it accordingly. If there is some obvious better approach I'm missing however feel free to enlighten me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a Dictionary which will be faster for a large number of elements but slower for only few due to it's overhead

```
Dictionary<Type, Action<NetMessage>> messageHandlers = new Dictionary<Type, Action<NetMessage>>();

void RegisterHandler(Type type, Action<NetMessage> handler)
{
    messageHandlers.Add(type, handler);
}

void MessageReceived(NetMessage message)
{
    messageHandlers[message.GetType()].Invoke(message);
}
```

You can then register for events using

```
RegisterHandler(typeof(NetMessageSubClass), delegate(NetMessage message)
{
    //NetMessageSubclass related stuff
});
```

There is also probably a much neater solution using generics but I can't think of it at the moment.

---

**EDIT** Here's the generic method

```
void RegisterHandler<T>(Action<T> handler) where T : NetMessage
{
    messageHandlers.Add(
        typeof(T),
        (NetMessage message) => handler.Invoke((T)message)
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there certainly is a better way to do this. This is a perfect example for polymorphism usage.

Declare a virtual method in your base abstract class (`NetMessage`):

```
//sidenote, the method
public virtual void DoCoolStuff(){}
```

And in your derived classes (`NetConnectMessage` and `NetMoveMessage`) **override** the method to do whatever it needs to do for that class in particular.

```
public override void DoCoolStuff(){
    //make it do cool stuff :D
}
```

And instead of the many if's and else's, you can now just call it like this:

```
NetMessage message = IncomingMessages.First.Value;
IncomingMessages.RemoveFirst();
message.DoCoolStuff();
```

That's exactly how polymorphism works: it will determine at runtime what type of message your message actually is, and call the appropriate method accordingly.

Comment: The thing is the messages do not do anything. All a message has in it is data that says what something wants to do. For example a Move Message cannot actually move anything because it doesn't have things like information about players to do something like that. The server is what actually has to simulate these things and then write new messages to be sent out based on those events.

Comment: Ah, okay. Then I do not understand the need to have message classes.

Well then, whatever approach you decide to use, it will come down to if/else somewhere (or writing a method with the same name, overloading them to receive a different argument for each type of message there is).